# terraform error while launching server in openstack

Tags: openstack, terraform

I'm getting below error while launching server in Openstack with Terraform:

> Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

Comment: Please consider adding your code, what have tried yet ?

Comment: I found the error. I was providing the incorrect url.

Answer (score 1):

Th Error was due to the incorrect url provided.
Basical I was providing the GUI url, for terraform the url is different,In mycase it was "http://IPAddress>:5000/v2.0"